# How to resolve IBM MQ error: 2393-MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR from dot net client for IBM MQ mTLS

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, mtls

I am working on IBM MQ mTLS set up for dot net client. We are using self-signed certificates for mTLS authentication. These are steps we followed,

1. Create key repository(.kdb) on queue manager and self-signed certificate
2. Create key repository(.kdb) on dot net application and self-signed certificate
3. Added those certificates into each repository.

Following are the connection properties set in Hash table:

```
    prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
    prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
    prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
    prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
    prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, @"C:\Personal\sslkey\key");
```

When making queue manager connection, I am getting below exception:
CompCode: 2, Reason: **2393**
Unhandled Exception: IBM.WMQ.MQException:** MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR**
at IBMMTLSSSL.MQConnection.WriteMsg(String strInputMsg)

Are there any other properties, we need to include when making connection?

Comment: What dll from IBM MQ are you using? Is the .Net framework or .Net Core/Standard? Windows or some other platform?

Comment: It is with .NET Framework and Windows platform and I am using amqmdnet.dll. After doing some research and changing certificate key repository, it is giving AMQ9637E: Channel is lacking a certificate.
What is the certificate label, I need to use at channel?

Comment: Are you using managed mode or unmanaged mode?